# Querying MongoDB Embedded Array

Tags: mongodb

I am having some trouble trying to query a field in Mongo. My document looks like this:

```
{
    "short_url": "DTsB9k",
    "long_url": "http://www.example.com",
    "date_created": {
        "$date": "2013-01-01T14:10:29.899Z"
    },
    "ips": {
        "24.184.209.227": {
            "ip_address": "12.34.56.78",
            "clicks": [
                {
                    "click_date": {
                        "$date": "2013-01-01T14:10:41.784Z"
                    },
                    "click_referrer": null
                },
                {
                    "click_date": {
                        "$date": "2013-01-01T14:31:32.440Z"
                    },
                    "click_referrer": null
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "users": {
        "4": {
            "user_id": "4",
            "date_added": {
                "$date": "2013-01-01T14:10:29.899Z"
            },
            "creator": true
        }
    },
    "total_clicks": 2,
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "50e2ee55569df0b469000000"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to query on the user_id, eventually there will be more than one. But I've tried

```
{ "users" : "4" }
{ "users.user_id" : "4" }
{ "users.*.user_id" : "4" }
```

None of these work. What am I doing wrong in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. {"users":4} would find only documents with users field which is equal to 4, or users field which is equal to an array containing an element which equals to 4
2. {"users.user_id":4} would have worked if you had user_id directly under the users object, but it is under the "4", so it fails to match
3. { "users.*.user_id" : "4" }  I don't think mongodb has such wildcard feature.

To fetch the record above you can try:

`{"users.4.user_id": "4"}`

---

edit:
If the "4" under "users" is the same as the user_id, you can also try the query:

`{"users.4":{$exists:true}}`